# update the same field twise

Tags: plsql

hye...i have 1 table name rumah that contain id, nama, jenis_rumah and sewa field. i need to update sewa field when nama like %RIZAL%, then update sewa*3. if jenis_rumah = cornet lot then update sewa with 20% discount. This is my pl/sql, but the update process is fail...need advice from expert. tq.

1st trial:

```
DECLARE CURSOR rec IS

SELECT id, nama, jenis_rumah, sewa
FROM rumah;

nama varchar2 (100);
jenis_rumah varchar2(100);
upd_cntr  NUMBER := 0;
tot_all      NUMBER :=0;

    BEGIN
    FOR z1 IN rec LOOP 

            if upper (nama) like '%RIZAL%' then 
                begin
                UPDATE rumah
                SET sewa = sewa*3
                where id = z1.id ;
                 end;

               elsif  jenis_rumah = 'CORNER LOT' THEN
               Begin
              UPDATE rumah
              SET sewa = (sewa * 80/100)
              where id = z1.id;
              end;

              END IF;      


            upd_cntr := upd_cntr + 1;
            tot_all := tot_all + 1;

        END LOOP; 

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Updated Sewa:' || tot_all);     
    END;
```

2nd trial:
i try on the different way, only nama like %RIZAL% is updated

```
DECLARE CURSOR rec IS

SELECT id, nama, jenis_rumah, SUM (sewa*3) AS upd_sewa
FROM rumah
WHERE UPPER (nama) LIKE '%RIZAL%'
GROUP BY id, nama, jenis_rumah, sewa;

jenis_rumah varchar2(100);
upd_cntr  NUMBER := 0;
tot_all      NUMBER :=0;

    BEGIN
    FOR z1 IN rec LOOP 

            UPDATE rumah
            SET sewa = z1.upd_sewa
            where id = z1.id ;

         IF  jenis_rumah = 'CORNER LOT' THEN
          UPDATE rumah
          SET sewa = (sewa * 80/100);
            END IF;      


            upd_cntr := upd_cntr + 1;
            tot_all := tot_all + 1;


        END LOOP; 

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Updated Sewa:' || tot_all);

    END;
```

Comment: Why do you need a procedure for this?

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't need a PL/SQL for what you are trying to achieve.

Try this instead:

```
 UPDATE rumah
        SET sewa = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN UPPER(nama) LIKE '%RIZAL%' THEN  sewa*3
                    WHEN jenis_rumah = 'CORNER LOT' THEN (sewa * 80/100)
                    ELSE sewa
                END
        ;
```

Comment: thanks, but there is error  inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Comment: @user1407005 What is the datatype of sewa?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a procedure.  Just run 2 update statements.

```
UPDATE rumah
   SET sewa = sewa*3
 where upper (nama) like '%RIZAL%';


UPDATE rumah
   SET sewa = (sewa * 80/100)
 where jenis_rumah = 'CORNER LOT';
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to run it manually, that why i need to put in procedure. what do you think??

Comment: @user1407005, you could put an update in a procedure too. But Cybernate's solution is probably a bit more elegant.